In Visual Studio, Power Tools issue with Created Powertools templates are not showing on powertools window - ASP.NET zero
I have created templates in project directory(AspNetZeroRadTool\FileTemplates) for Power Tools(Visual studio extension). But, the option to choose the created feature using power tools templates on Power Tools window is not present.
I tried editing Power Tools templates to create a new template but not showing on Power Tools window.
Correct me If i'm mistakenly understood the concept.

This does not seem related to Postgres. Please explain and show how it relates, or remove the tag.

Yes, Its is not related to postgresql but it is related to Asp.net Zero.

The Power tools template don't show on power tools extension. But, if we write
code by understanding the documentation provided by Asp.net zero team it will generate the files(server side), feature(Agular - client side) for all the generated entities. Please follow the updated documentation. Click the link here
